# WKTapGestureRecognizer Two taps triggering one also

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

A simple question, I don't even need to post the code. I did some research on a UITapGestureRecognizer, and noticed there is a require fail method that makes it so when you tap twice it doesn't trigger tap one as well.... I have two tap gesture recognizers on my watch, one is for one tap and the other is for two taps. When I tap twice, it also triggers the tap one GestureRecognizer. Anyone know how to avoid this situation?

Comment: I am using an Apple Watch for years now but never got the situation to use a double tab to trigger an action. Why not to use force touch ?

Comment: I use 3 gestures in this app, one is force touch.

Comment: Implement the `shouldBeRequiredToFail` delegate.

Comment: WKTapGestureRecognizer does not include shouldBeRequiredToFail

Answer (score 1):

In case of WatchOS, there is  `Must Fail First` option in the storyboard which you can drag to the other `WKTapGestureRecognizer` that should fail for the one-tap gesture to succeed.[image: Attribute inspector]

you can find this option in the `Attribute inspector` of the gesture recognizer object